# Add Google Play Services to Native Extension for Adobe AIR Android

Tags: android, air, google-play-services, air-native-extension, ane

Okay, I would like to know if anyone managed to pull this thing of? I am making native extension and my native JAR uses Google Play Services via reflection. I have added Google Play Services library to my native extension, here's how `platform.xml` looks like:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency>
        <packagedDependency>google-play-services.jar</packagedDependency>
    </packagedDependencies>
    <packagedResources>
        <packagedResource>
            <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName>
            <folderName>google-play-services-res</folderName>
        </packagedResource>
    </packagedResources>
</platform>
```

My `android` build folder has structure like this:

```
android
- nativeLib.jar
- android-support-v4.jar
- google-play-services-res (folder)
- google-play-services.jar
- library.swf
```

When I build my ANE w/o Google Play Services library (which has around 5.1 mb), I see that my ANE has for example 800 kb. After adding Google Play Services dependency like this, ANE has around 6 mb which for me indicates that these JARs stated in `platform.xml` are somehow bundled in native extension. Now, my native JAR has some function where I can see if calling method from Google Play Services library fails or not. It always fails when I call it from AIR Android app I made and where I integrated this generated ANE.

So, my `native` JAR and `google-play-services` JAR are standing next to each other before packing them in my ANE, but after triggering method from my native jar, it turns out that it isn't aware that google-play-services.jar is anywhere around.

Just for the record, I don't have any issues in bridging AIR with native library, all calls are working properly and interface I am exposing to ActionScript files is fully functional, it's just that native library is performing certain actions depending on wether Google Play Services are found or not and in my case -> they are never found.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong and how to pull this thing of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get a hold of **google-play-services-.jar**??  That's not provided as a jar by Google...

Comment: Well, once you have downloaded Google play Services onto your computer, you can find it in google-play-services_lib folder if you are using Mac OS X as I do.

Comment: No, still no JAR.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this ANE:

https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-GooglePlayServices

We've packaged both those libraries and resources in that ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't able to locate this repository in my searches, weird. :/ Anyhow, at the end I ended up wrapping google-play-services.jar into ANE with (at the moment) no ActionScript interface at all, because for my particular case I don't need any. I will stick with mine implementation because I just need some parts of Google Play Services library and with https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42 I leave in library only things I need thus causing resulting ANE to be 2.6M instead of 10.7M like in your project. I will eventually post answer how I did it.

Comment: Also just wanted to note that stripping out the other libraries can be problematic if you intend on using other ANE's . So just take care if you are using any other Google related ANE's

Comment: @Michael  How do I use your **.ane** file in place of google-play-services.jar?

Comment: Hi, 
Our Google Play Services ANEs simply wrap the appropriate jars and resources from the play services libraries. So if you are making an ANE build against a version of the play services library however don't package them with your ANE, but instead include our ANEs.  Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Google Play Services working (with just the necessary JAR files) using this code:

https://github.com/Oldes/ANEAmanitaAndroid-public/tree/GooglePlay

You can see what I did to have it working from the minimal "hello" ANE using this pull request details:

https://github.com/Oldes/ANEAmanitaAndroid-public/pull/1

I've got the GPS jar files from SDK extracting them from AAR archives like:

`extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\play-services-base-9.4.0.aar`

In each `aar` (which is just a `zip`) file is `classes.jar` which I just copy and rename as `play-services-base-9.4.0.jar` in my project.

Also to have the GPS running correctly, you must specify correct application ID in the app manifest like [at this line](https://github.com/Oldes/ANEAmanitaAndroid-public/pull/1/commits/915dbf879a9bc8039fd47a446294cd66509cbe3b#diff-bcc1a5d5559bad109bebd002f9f51a45R31):